# Is $\int _0^a\:\frac{d}{dx}\:\int ^x_0U\left(t\right)dt\:dx\:=\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^x\int _0^aU\left(t\right)dt\:dx\:=\:\:\int _0^aU\left(t\right)dt$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

If $U'\left(x\right)=u\left(x\right)$, Find $V'(x)$ if $V\left(x\right)=\left(a-x\right)U\left(x\right)+\int _0^xU\left(t\right)dt\:$. Hence prove that $\int _0^a\:U\left(x\right)dx\:=aU\left(0\right)+\int _0^a\left(a-x\right)u\left(x\right)dx\:$

So my solution was to leave the $\int _0^xU\left(t\right)dt$ from $V'(x)$ as $\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^xU\left(t\right)dt$, then for the proof, I had $$-\int _0^a\:U\left(x\right)dx\:=\int _0^aU\left(t\right)dt\:+...+-\int _0^a\:\frac{d}{dx}\:\int ^x_0U\left(t\right)dt\:dx\:\:$$ and my proof would be complete if $$\int _0^a\:\frac{d}{dx}\:\int ^x_0U\left(t\right)dt\:dx\:=\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^x\int _0^aU\left(t\right)dt\:dx\:=\:\:\int _0^aU\left(t\right)dt$$ (from the title), such that the $\int _0^aU\left(t\right)dt$ cancel out. However, I don't know if this is valid. By Fubini's theorem, it would be valid since I'm pretty sure the $x$ from the integral bound in not a function but a number that you are integrating up to. So it is real number?

The solutions simplified $\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^xU\left(t\right)dt$ but if I leave it inthat form, is the rest of my work valid?

Comment: What does $\int_0^x\dots\,\mathrm{d}x$ mean?

Comment: Just read your last line which says you have already seen the solution that simplifies $\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x U(t) dt$. Coming to your working, why not show $\int _0^a\:\frac{d}{dx}\:[\int ^x_0U\left(t\right)dt\: ] dx\: = \int _0^a\: U\left(x\right)\:dx\:$. That should work for your proof, right?

Comment: @MathLover yes, this is what my question was about. So it **is** indeed true (as per my question title? $\int _0^a\:\frac{d}{dx}\:[\int ^x_0U\left(t\right)dt\: ] dx\: = \int _0^a\: U\left(x\right)\:dx\:$ .

Comment: @user10354138 Integral from $0$ to $x$. Is $x$ here a number or a function? If it is a function I believe I can apply Fubini's theorem. However, **now I am also unsure where it is valid to bring the** $\frac{d}{dx}$ **out the front**. Should it be in between the two integrals? I belive they can cancel out since they are inverse operations, so perhaps either notation is fine?

Comment: @user71207 Is $x$ a dummy or not?  If it is a dummy it shouldn't appear in the upper limit.  If it isn't then it is fixed so $\int\dots\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't make sense.  Either way, $\int_0^x\dots\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't make any sense, in particular, $\int_0^x\int_0^a U(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^x\int_0^a U(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x$ don't make sense.

Comment: @user71207 $\int _0^a\:\frac{d}{dx}\:[\int ^x_0U\left(t\right)dt\: ] dx\: = \int _0^a\: U\left(x\right)\:dx\:$ yes it is true. My point is that the intermediate step where you bring $\frac{d}{dx}$ out should not be there.

Comment: @user10354138 is it not the fundamental theorem of calculus? $\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^xU\left(t\right)dt = U(x)$

Comment: @MathLover What should the simplification be instead then?

Comment: @user71207 No.  $\int_0^x F\,\mathrm{d}x$ just simply doesn't make any sense.  On the other hand, $\int_0^x F\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^x F\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_0^x F\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^x F\,\mathrm{d}u=\dots$ does.

Comment: @user10354138 Notice it is $dt$ not $dx$

Comment: @user71207 But that is not what you wrote in the question, e.g., the middle term of the second displayed equation.

Comment: @user71207 no simplification needed. $\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^xU\left(t\right)dt = U(x)$ by fundamental theorem of calculus, right? Anyway it is a long series of comments so will stop here.

Comment: @user10354138 then I am not sure. This is from a Cambridge mathematics textbook. What should it be instead then?

Comment: Oh I see. The question is not wrong. My working out was wrong. Nevertheless, what should my working out be corrected to if $\int_0^x\dots\,\mathrm{d}x$ is invalid?

Comment: You just omit the middle term and say "fundamental theorem of calculus".